# IFrame Fills Area on PhoneGap instead of Fixed Position

Tags: android, cordova, iframe

My app works perfectly fine in the browser.

[image: what my app should look like]

What I do is I show and hide this iFrame using a checkbox.
However when I released it for android, the new iFrame I added fills the entire page instead of having it's fixed position which I stated in CSS.

[image: what my app currently looks like]

I'm converting my app to an Android app using PhoneGap Build.
My app uses the following permissions.

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>

<access origin="*"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Can someone explain why my app fills the page and does anyone know of a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am also working on a PhoneGap app at the moment and it's cool seeing someone else using it! Glad you solved your problem, I still don't understand how you solved it 'merge' and all but glad you did.

Comment: I took the source code from the html file I had in the iframe and put it into my main app. (All the html, css and javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I was able to fix the problem two different ways.
I merged the html of that page into my main app and merged the script into my main script.
I also fixed it using the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) JQuery API.

Even though I was able to solve my problem here I still don't understand why the iFrame filled the entire page.